# Java integration in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I have a simple, single-file Java program that functions on it's own just fine, but it's command line only. I wanted to try using Processing to give it an interface and some animations.

Is that possible?

I have .pde with a .java in the same folder so that when I open my sketch I can see the .java in another tab. In my sketch file I threw in some basic setup() and draw(), but when I run it I get an InstantiationException. Has anyone tried something like this successfully?

Comment: By the way, I'm referring to Processing.org Processing. http://processing.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran a basic test and all compiles fine with Processing 1.5.1 :

```
void setup(){
  new Test();
}
//Test.java in separate tab
class Test{
  Test(){   System.out.println("Hello!"); }
}
```

Comment: The problem I was having (I believe) stemmed from attempting to call a class in my .java file with the same name as my .pde ...Sigh. Oh, well. I changed the name and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the response, though. An up-vote and a check for you, sir.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir :) Btw, the Processing 'IDE' is ok for quick'n'dirty sketches, but at the moment it's more like an enhanced text editor than an IDE, so for larger projects I don't recommend it. One other thing it does is pack all your 'tabs' into a single Java [PApplet](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html) that gets compiled. If you're comfortable with Java and eclipse I recommend giving the [Proclipsing](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) plugin a try. Goodluck !